# Ponteiro para função

Tags: c

Gostaria de fazer uma pergunta que fica melhor com um exemplo:

Tenho o seguinte trecho de código em C:

```
char texto[]="String";
int (*ret)() = (int(*)())texto;
```

Neste trecho acima, vi que é declarado um ponteiro para função chamado ret, porém não entendi o que é atribuido a ele.

Seria um casting? Tipo, ele pega o endereço de `texto[]` e o converte para uma função?

Comment: Não entendi, parece que esta perguntando pra alguém em específico.

Comment: Desculpem, nunca tinha postado aqui kkkkkkk
Não sabia corretamente como funcionava

Comment: @user39224 como o Bacco disse: da uma passeada pelo tuor, vai descobrir como funciona o site ganhara medalhas e conseguira tirar mais duvidas ainda!

Comment: @user39224 editei sua pergunta para ficar mais adequada ao formato do site, mas fica a recomendação de ler a documentação aqui: [Tour] e [Ask] para que nas próximas (ou mesmo se quiser editar esta pergunta) você consiga elaborar melhor a postagem.

Comment: Obrigado, vou ler sim.

Comment: @user39224 além de ler os tópicos mencionados, se registre e venha fazer parte da comunidade, temos muito a aprender e você não vai perder com isso :)

Comment: Você consegue dar um exemplo funcional disto? Consegue postar um código com mais contexto? Onde achou isto? Dê uma olhada em http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve